# Is Spring tightly coupled with maven

Tags: spring, maven, build, build-process

Is Spring tightly coupled with Maven ? Most of the examples in the internet  shows Spring and Maven to configure spring dependent jars, [this](http://kent.spillner.org/blog/work/2009/11/14/java-build-tools.html) post explains so many cons of Maven. All commercial projects are  should to be using only this combination ?

Please explain

Thanks

Comment: If you don't like maven just use other build tools as already mentioned Gradle, Ant+Ivy what ever you like. Apart from that the article in the link shows in so many aspects that the poster of the article hasn't understand Maven nor worked in larger projects with it and the article is about 4 1/2 years old which is an eternity.

Comment: Dont read too much into that post. Its written by someone who has tried maven but doesnt really know what theyre doing. Basically it translates into one con: For advanced usage, maven has a relatively steep learning curve

Answer (score 2):

Both of them serve different purposes, Spring examples use Maven because maven is highly adopted as a build, dependency management framework. That has nothing to do with Spring coupling with Maven. Spring is a framework to build enterprise applications and Maven is a build and deploy tool.

You can use Gradle, ivy or even manually download the libraries instead of relying on Maven as the dependency management framework.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can use whatever you want to build your Spring-based app. BTW, all the Spring tutorials show examples using Gradle (that Spring also uses internally).

What is true, though, is that Spring jars are available from the Maven central repository and the Spring repository, and that their dependencies is thus described in a Maven pom.xml file. But nothing prevents you from downloading the required jars manually and add them in the classpath.